# Determining the user's time and date in PHP

Tags: php, datetime

I want to be able to get the time of the person using the PHP script.

I don't know what time zone they will be in, etc.

Is there not a way of just saying 'get the time of the user' rather than setting timezones?

Comment: How would php know what timezone the person is in?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. There are only three ways to get the time zone of the user:

1. **Ask the user**
2. **Use JavaScript** to check the time client-side and send it to your server with an AJAX request, a cookie, etc. -- only works if JS is enabled and doesn't work for the first request
3. **Use an IP-to-location database** to locate the user and determine their time zone from the location -- more than 5% of the time with any commercial database, your location at the city level will be wrong

Comment: All approaches are useful, and #1 is correct as often as #2. Correctness is a context-sensitive concept! If someone's registering and your app provides time-specific reports, you should be asking them for the time zone they want to display the reports in, not guessing by JavaScript or any other means. Not only is JavaScript not always available, but the time zone of their computer is not always the correct time zone -- traveling in another country, borrowing someone else's computer, simply having the clock set wrong, etc.

Comment: #1 is best, if possible; javascript is often incorrect, but people generally know where they are.

Comment: javascript would give you the timezone set up on user's computer. It doesn't mean he necessarily wants to see data in this timezone - he may be travelling, for example. So asking is the best, but the default for asking may be one from Javascript/IP. Also note that there are different timezones that can have at times similar offsets, and Javascript would just give you the offset, not the actual zone.

Answer (score 5):

No, there is not. The only thing you get to know about your users "for free" is what can be communicated via the [HTTP protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_headers), and that doesn't include "user timezone."

You *could* use Javascript to get the time from the browser, but that's not guaranteed to be accurate.

You *could* try to geolocate the user, but that's even less accurate.

The user will know best himself, ask him.

Answer (score 1):

> the person using the php script.

That's the webserver. If you mean the person requesting the PHP script, you don't know their timezone unless they're nice enough to send it to you. Firefox does not appear to, although some may.

The answer here is to use Javascript to get the local time and either do what needs doing client-side, or send it to the server somehow - but that's a different question.